# How can i write this php code inside html form action correctly?

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to put this code

```
$test= 'echo'.'<? php $_POST["op"] ?>';
```

inside this form action

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="delete_admin.php?id='.$row['id'].'" method="post">
```

before putting it, i get a correct link

> http://localhost/delete_admin.php?id=34

after inserting it like that

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="delete_admin.php?id='.$row['id'].''. $test.'" method="post">
```

i get

> http://localhost/delete_admin.php?id=&op=test

which the second parametre showed correcly but the first one missed up

also, there's `" method="post">` showing up in the page

So, how can i fix that ? maybe something in single quotes or double quotes

After 2 hours of trying still can't figure it out :/

Appreciate any help !

Comment: Some things: not sure what `<? php $_POST["op"] ?>` is supposed to do, there's no need for `<?php ?>`. `http://localhost/delete_admin.php?id=&op=test` Where's the `echo` gone from your `$test` declaration? How did the `&` get in there? Where does `op=` come from? Do you `echo` that complete `<form>...` line?

Comment: @kerbholz sorry for the confusion, i fixed it using post as suggested by Simone, check answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start studying the difference between POST / GET, the first one you send the data directly on the server side without the possibility to see it, instead GET passes through the url.
Given your situation I recommend using POST as follows:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="delete_admin.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
```

In the *delete_admin.php*:

```
$test= $_POST["id"];
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me to figure it out, appreciate your help !

Comment: Yes don't worry :)